# How to redirect another page with value object

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have a spring 3 application where i am using jquery to post ajax request. Now i want to redirect my page to another page after ajax response comes. A Pojo is returned by the 1st page controller, which is to be passed to 2nd contoller. i know how to redirect but have no idea how to pass this PoJo to next form controller

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/xxx/xxx/xxx/accept",
                    data: "bId=" + bId+
                    "&minDelTime=" +minDelTime,
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.errorText == null)  {
                                                //this works fine
                            alert(response.orderId);
//this is where i have to redirect with response as parameter                           
window.location.replace("/xxx/xxx/xxx/confirm/"+response.orderId);

                        }   else    {
                            alert(response.errorText);
                        }                       
                      },
```

My next page controller -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/xxx/xxx/confirm")
public class ConfirmationController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/orderVo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showOrderConfirmPage(@PathVariable MasterVo orderVo, Model model) {
        LOGGER.info("Entry showOrderConfirmPage()");
        LOGGER.debug("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ : " + orderVo.toString());
        LOGGER.info("Exit showOrderConfirmPage()");
        return "/xxx/orderConfirmView";
    }
}
```

But i am getting error always. Can someone please tell me how to pass object(Pojo) to new page controller?

Update -

I tried serializing object -

```
success: function(response){
                        if(response.errorText == null)  {
                    $.post("orderVo", response.serialize(), function(data) {
                window.location.replace("/xxx/xxx/xxx/confirm/");
                            });
```

but i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'serialize'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just redirect?

```
return "redirect:/xxx/orderConfirmView";
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about serialization.

Are you using jQuery? There is a simple method to serialize data from HTML form.

Comment: yes i am using jQuery and have updated my code to above but now i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'serialize' error

Comment: Where that data comes from? jQuery operates on html and forms. You have to serialize form, not object (in jQuery).

Comment: Yes, this is the issue, data is coming from spring controller class as a Java POJO object and i want to pass this object to another controller